# C++ - How to create a makefile for a main.cpp which is using a library that I created?

Tags: c++

Normally I use this very simple template:

```
main.exec: main.cpp
g++ main.cpp -o main.exec

clean:
rm -f *.exec *.out *.err
```

Yet here, my cpp file uses one of my libraries. I want to create a makefile that compiles my main.cpp file with its library and to build a static library containing the function I created in the library. Thank you

Comment: Even though you have a library, you must have included the headers in your main.cpp file or somewhere in your project. Thus include the path of those files, ie `-Ipath_to_the_folder_containing_the_headers` etc, `-llib_names_used`

Comment: Yes, it is in the header of my main.cpp file. My library is in the same folder as my main.cpp file